# Hot wiring 2002 C230

Tags: mercedes-benz

I need to move this mercedes I use it for spares and can't afford to buy it new keys. I have removed the ignition, hoping that I could  Please say it's possible

Comment: hmmmmmmmmm   We typically avoid this kind of an answer for obvious reasons.  Someone may come along and share though.  Good luck!

Comment: Simply lift it onto a trailer or tow it.

Comment: Why not just put it in neutral and push it?

Comment: I suspect that the car has a chipped key style security system. This means that even if you could hot wire the car, it won't run.

Comment: @vini_i  The BCM is one of the better car industry implementations IMO.

Comment: @DucatiKiller the problem is that the internal software security of the BCM and other computers in the car, is something awful. There have been multiple stories now, of people hacking them through the diagnostic connector and driving away without a key at all (smart key cars). The NHTSA of all people recently issued guidelines on how software should be written to help reduce the vulnerabilities.

Comment: @vini_i  Indeed.  There are holes and I've read the articles but now that BCM's are in place there is room for iterative improvement over time.  The previous paradigm had no such ability.  It was, cut the wires and drive away.

Comment: you could try putting the car in gear and jumping the starter with some remote wire setup it might be easier than pushing the car.

Comment: I knoe its a sceptical question to answer, but I have to move this car Pronto and don't have days to wait for a replacement key. Here's a picture of the car to prove that it's a wreck

Comment: You can't just put an automatic into neutral otherwise it would have been done.

Comment: Push it off a cliff and collect the insurance money....Like the old joke about mixed emotions.  Seeing your former in-laws drive your brand new Mercedes off a cliff in a ball of flames...then realizing your fully covered, :)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't give you the answer you were looking for, but I'll post it here in case it gives you a desirable end result.

They don't make it as easy as on other vehicles, but you can shift it into neutral without starting it. This was on a C240, but should be the same or similar case for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MB4p-G5uXyo Basically, pull off the bezel around the shifter, lift a little black tab on the bottom, and you can then shift it as needed (e.g. neutral).

Answer (score 2):

> You can't just put an automatic into neutral otherwise it would have
>   been done.

You most certainly can if you defeat the shifter interlock, as @atraudes suggests.

Or get under it and move the manual valve and get the parking pawl out manually,  If it's a wreck you can chock it and leave it in neutral.

Or better yet, throw a chain around the front suspension and drag it out with a pickup.  Might break the parking pawl (bonus!) but I doubt it.

Comment: Or disconnect the drive shafts?

Comment: @SteveMatthews Seems like work.  But I own a 7.3 Powerstroke Dually, so I take great pleasure in pulling stumps...   errr "*parts cars*".   Serously 10 minutes of work defeating the shift interlock, and a broken Yugo can drag this around.  I don't know where the drama lies.